# how do I make an image fit inside a button in css?

Tags: html, css

I created two buttons on my site that I plan to turn them into images when you hover over them. The problem that I ran into is that after hovering, the image does not quite fit inside the box (it is too big). How do I resize it so that it properly fits inside the box upon hovering over them?

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="link.html">
<div class="main-button">
<h2 class="main-text">Maintenance</h2>  
</div></a>


<a href="link2.html">
<div class="docs-button">   
<h4 class="docs-text">Other Documents</h4>  
</div></a>
```

and the CSS:

```
.main-button {
width: 230px;
height: 230px;
border: 5px solid white;
overflow: hidden;
background: #0099DF;
margin-left:100px;
float:left;
}

.main-text {
font-size: 24px;
color:#FFFFFF;
top: 110px;
height: 80px;
width: 170px;
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:150px;
}

.docs-button {
width: 230px;
height: 230px;
border: 5px solid white;
overflow: hidden;
background: #545454;
margin-right:100px;
position:fixed; 
right:30%;
float:center;
}

.docs-text {
font-size: 24px;
color:#FFFFFF;
top: 110px;
height: 80px;
width: 170px;
margin-left:60px;
margin-top:120px;
}

.main-button:hover {
background-image:url('../images/settings.png');


}

.docs-button:hover {
background-image:url('../images/documents.png');
}
```

Comment: look for background-size.  float:center; doesn't exist !!!

Comment: background-size: cover does it. Yep, just learned that there is no such thing as float:center. CSS newbie here.

Answer (score 3):

Try `background-size:cover` - e.g.

```
.main-button:hover {
    background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
    background-size:cover;
}

.docs-button:hover {
    background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Cover seems to do the same thing as contains in this case. It definitely looks better now than it did before, but as I mentioned in the previous comment, I guess there is no way to make it fill it completely without making it look stretched.

Comment: Can you screenshot how it appears with your images?

Comment: I actually just used a different image that worked better to fill it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

background-size:contain if you want to see all image, or 100% 100% to take 100% width and 100% height but in this case your image could be shell

Comment: Contains works for the most part, but there is still a colored border around the image. I guess maybe it cannot fill the entire button without looking stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Hello `TheOrangeRemix`,

I have a viable solution to you problem. My first step would be to look at the properties of you image and get the dimensions e.g. `100x100`, `255x100`, etc.

From here you will want to convert that ratio into a percentage. This is a tool I often use when calculating ratio percentages: [Ratio to Percentage Calculator](https://www.miniwebtool.com/ratio-to-percentage-calculator/?numerator=1080&denominator=1920)

Once you have your percentage (I'm going to use 1:2, which gives me the percentage of 50%). You want to create an anchor tag (`<a>`) and give it some styles:

(**Note**: this may be slightly overengineered but it does what you want it to.)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.mainButton {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100x50');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mainButton .text {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="/somewhere/something" class="mainButton">
    <span class="text">
        Hello, I am a button.
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding:

```
width="100%" height="100%"
```

to the img properties worked for me